# Path in a multigraph connecting two vertices of a block is contained in the block

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a connected multigraph

let B be a block of G , and let P be a path in G connecting two vertices of B. Show that P is contained in B

Comment: The question is answered. Do you need anything else? It is listed as "not having a good answer".

Answer (score 1):

Your proof needs just a little cleaning: We can assume that $P$ connecting $X$ and $Y$ is a union of two paths: $P_1\subseteq B$ connecting $X,Z$ and $P_2\subset B^c$ (the complement of $B$) connecting $Z$ and $Y$. We can also assume that every vertex in $P_2$ appears in  $P_2$ only once. Then proceed as in your proof. $B$ is connected, hence there is a simple path $Q$ in $B$ connecting $Y$ and $Z$. Then the union $P_2\cup Q$ is a cycle not contained in a single block, a contradiction.